# How to create a C# host program for a Q# program in Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: programming, q#

I have been trying to create a C# host program for a Q# program in Visual Studio Community 2019 by following these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/install-cs?tabs=tabid-vs2019%2Ctabid-csharp.

But when I click "Create", I cannot complete the process, and this message pops up:

[image]

I have followed the instructions from the message, have restarted my computer, and have reopened Visual Studio. However, that same message still pops up, and I still cannot create the C# host program.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the error happens when you click create for the Q# project, or for the C# project (or both).
Also, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: The error occurs only when I try to create the C# project. I use Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition (version 16.6.30320.27).

Comment: I don't think this has to do with Q#, it looks more like a .NET issue